# Should I store my Rails 3 observers in the app/models directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

or do they belong in their own place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you generate one (e.g., "rails g observer Test") that's where it goes, so I'd stick with the convention.

Answer (score 11):

I agree with the convention, but when you find you've got a lot of observers in app/models, you might want to go ahead and store all your observers in app/observers. (There are also [some gems](https://github.com/jamesgolick/observational) to help streamline your design).

Just remember to add app/observers to your app's configured load path.